# WARNING: Module not found [ssl]

Tags: ssl, centos, geoserver

I am trying to install GeoServer on Centos folling installation documentation in GeoServer website, I have got the error "WARNING: Module not found [ssl]" after this line "GEOSERVER DATA DIR is /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir", what can be the problem for me?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning and does not prevent operation.  I believe this error is common with the GeoServer bundle which comes with Jetty.

If you need to configure https support, then I'd recommend investigating Tomcat or Wildly.